# Command pattern for multiple receiver types

Tags: design-patterns, c++

I have a tree-like structure of objects. Objects have different types but all of them are inherited from the same base class. Now I want to send some kind of command objects to the nodes. Command object has address of the target node and should be passed through root node and intermediate nodes untill it reaches the target node. Target node accepts command and allows it to perform some actions on the node:

```
void Node::processCommand (Command& cmd) {
    if(cmd.address == this->address)
        cmd.execute(this);
    else
        child[cmd.address]->processCommand(cmd);
}
```

First question: is it a command pattern, or may be some of it's kind?

Next, consider I have nodes of classes ClassA and ClassB and I want to send some commands to objects of both classes, and some commands only for objects of ClassB, something like that:

```
class CommandForBoth {
    void execute (BaseClass* obj) {
         obj->doSomething();
    }
}

class CommandForB {
    void execute (ClassB* obj) {
         obj->doSomethingSpecial();
    }
}
```

Is it possible to implement that without casts and without multiple methods for passing commands of different types, like:

```
void Node::processCommand (CommandForBoth& cmd);
void Node::processCommand (CommandForClassA& cmd);
void Node::processCommand (CommandForClassB& cmd);
```

Comment: Not really sure about the first part of your question (other than that if it works I see nothing wrong with it). The second part, however, looks like it will be a good fit for some variant of the Visitor pattern. You may also be able to do something with templates to make it work, but I haven't been working in c++ for a while now so struggle to think the right easy to design templates....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Is it a command pattern ?

The **[command pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/command-pattern.html)** implies that:

1. All the commands share the same interface.  In C++ this is usually done with inheritance from an abstract `Command`.
2. A `Client` creates a concrete command and sets the `Receiver`.
3. An `Invoker` launches the command, which will carry out its actions for the already defined `Receiver`.

Your approach does not meet these expectations:

1. `CommandForBoth` and `CommandB` do not share the same interface (but maybe you just didn't mention it in your snippet).
2. Your command doesn't know its receiver:  instead of the `Client` defining it at creation, it's the `Invoker` who defines the target at execution.
3. The `Invoker` is your initial `Node`.  But your Invoker might not launch the command,  but forward it to one of it's child.

#### Or is it a visitor pattern ?

A **[visitor pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/visitor-pattern.html)** is designed for executing operations on an `ObjectStructure`.  The structure is responsible to activate the visitor for its relevant element.  Each element is responsible to invoke the visitor for their relevant sub-elements.

This looks very close to what you are doing:

- The initial `Node` corresponds to the `ObjectStructure`,
- Each `Node` corresponds to an `Element`
- `Node::ProcessCommand(Command)` corresponds to `Element::accept(Visitor)`
- `Command` corresponds to `Visitor`
- `Command::execute(Node)` corresponds to `Visitor::visit(Node)`

The only unusual thing is that in a visitor pattern, the successive chain of `accept()` is in general performed by the elements to call the visitor for all the children, whereas here, the `accept()` only looks at the addressing and executes the visitor if the addressing matches.

#### Implementation without cast

The visitor pattern has a solution for your casting issue: each `Visitor` (so for you, each `Command`) has an override of `visit()` (so for you: `execute()`) for each of the different subtypes of `Elements` (i.e. `Nodes`) that exist.  In your case, all the overrides but one would implement nothing (or will throw an exception).

This is a drawback of the visitor pattern, that you may not want.  Alternatively, if the `Nodes` are  polymorphic, you could easily deviate from the "pure" visitor pattern, and use only one `execute(BaseClass*)`:

```
class CommandForB {
    void execute (BaseClass* obj) {
         ClassB bobj = dynamic_cast<ClassB*>(obj); 
         if (bobj) 
             bobj->doSomethingSpecial();
         else {  // ouch execute was invoked for an Node it shouldn't 
                // either do nothing, or log the unexpected situation, 
                // or throw an exception
         }
    }
}
```